# How to declare libc++.dylib dependency from iOS framework with static library

Tags: ios, frameworks, static-libraries, libc++

I have a problem with an iOS framework of mine (for use in Cocoa applications). It contains a static library, but it does not record the fact that it has a dependency on `libc++.dylib` (LLVM's STL implementation).

This means that users of my framework have to manually add `libc++.dylib` whenever they add my framework. Unless they know what to do, this is not a trivial obstacle.

Who is an expert on Apple frameworks? How can this dependency be declared such that the inclusion of `libc++.dylib` happens automatically when the users application is linked?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the option `-lc++` in `Other Linker Flags` for your build target in the application that is using the static library